# Purely resistive transformer circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I need to find \$Z_{ab}\$ for this circuit, But I don't have the value of ***k*** or ***M***, how do I choose a value that results in a purely resistive circuit and find \$Z_{ab}\$?

We know that \$\omega = 4000{\rm\,rad/s}\$.

So far I know that to find \$Z_{ab}\$ we need to add together ***Z self-induced*** and ***Z reflected***, using the formula below we can find \$Z_{ab}\$:

$$Z_{ab}=(R_1+j\omega L_1) + \frac{\omega^2 M^2} {R_2+j\omega L_2+Z_L}.$$

What I'm stuck on is how do I find M for this formula where Zab is purely resistive?

Comment: What work have you done so far, what have you attempted and where are you stuck?

Comment: What formula do you have that relates the inductance of a transformer's windings to it's turn ratio?

Comment: We were not given any formulas that relate the inductance of a transformer's windings to it's turn ratio

Answer (score 1):

You only need to solve for \$M\$. From that you can get \$k\$: $$k=M/\sqrt{L_1 L_2}.$$

As for making \$Z_{ab}\$ resistive - you'll be solving to make its imaginary part equal to zero. So, per the \$Z_{ab}\$ formula that you posted - and I've not checked if it's correct - you'd have:

$$\begin{aligned}
Z_{ab} \equiv R_{ab}+jX_{ab} &= (R_1+j\omega L_1) + \frac{\omega^2 M^2} {R_2+j\omega L_2+Z_L} \\
X_{ab} &= 0 \text{ for }Z_{ab}\text{ to be resistive.}
\end{aligned}$$

This is a system of equations that you can solve. First, you'll calculate \$Z_L\$, substitute into the fraction, and perform the complex division to get its complex value in standard form:

$$R_{ab}+j X_{ab} = (R_1+j\omega L_1) + (R_x+j\omega X_x).$$

Then, solve for

$$X_{ab} = \omega (L_1 + X_x) = 0.$$

\$Z_L\$ is the impedance of C1 it seems. So you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you, I am just still confused on how I should go about solving for k?